# Multiple NSTimer with individual timeleft

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I want to write a method that creates multiple NSTimer (the number of nstimer wont be known beforehand, code should be generic) and it will call a single method as its selector which updates timeleft as its text. Basically a countdown. 
Now as for the many timers, that many labels must exist and i have done this when the number of timer n label(which are same) are known beforehand, by creating that much nstimer and their each timeleft as instance variables, objects.

But each timer has their own timeleft. 
My question is- Is it possible to maintain multiple nstimer of unkwown quantity to run a single method(all timer calls that method) where each timer will have its individual countdown, or its timeleft, as to how many times the timer will run.
If so, what should be the logic.

Comment: Research the `userInfo` property on NSTimer

Comment: have tried, even if i sent the timeleft for each NSTimer as its userinfo, the method its calling wont know which timer its being sent from.

Comment: I would use a single timer, which is always running, at a 1 second interval.  Then maintain the individual "timeleft" values in an array, perhaps with an associated pointer to the relevant text field, and perform the timeleft decrement and updating of the text field in a loop in the timer fire method.  This will be much simpler to maintain and run better too.

Comment: Still doesnt solve the issue, the method wont know from which particular timer it is being called at an instant of time, and so , I cant write a generic code as to what index of the array of the Countdown array it must fetch.

Comment: A single timer is the best approach, but if you did want multiple timers all you need to do is store an NSNumber in userInfo that is the index of the label.

Comment: On each timer tick you would iterate the array and decrement all non-zero timers

Comment: and There is no textfield, just labels which updates the timer's tick. as HH:MM:SS  I cant use NSDate as each has individual time for ITS timer to run, as to 1st timer has 2000 seconds left and 2nd timer has 100 seconds left.

Comment: I cant use any label info as the label text is being updated as per timer's tick. and the Label has no recognition that a timer is being associated with it, And yes i need to have multiple timers as all the timer will run simultaneously.

Comment: Well i got to say the Single timer is a good logic, i might be able to work on that and reduce the Whole thing onto a single timer, Cheers for that :) but still that timeleft for each one are a problem.

Comment: Store an array of NSNumber integers. Hours left = number/3600. Minutes left = (Number-hours*3600)/60 and similar for seconds. The label doesn't need to "recognise" that it has a timer associated with it. You must have a reference to all of the labels, presumably in an array

Comment: You could create a custom object holding the timeleft (`unsigned`) and `UILabel` pointer and hold these in an array.  As labels are added, you add these custom objects to the array.  Removing them as necessary (searching for the label in this custom object).  "all the timer will run simultaneously" doesn't make any sense, assuming you want +/- 1 second intervals.  Using a custom object allows you to delegate the work to a method in that object, for example `updateTime`, which will make the code neater.  I will add an example implementation as an answer.

Comment: all the timer will run simultaneously - not nessesary, yes interval in each timer will be +/-1 but in between timer1 shifting from 3-2, in the half second timer2 might already change from say, 8-7, so that is why i said multiple timers. but i guess i can work it out somehow/

Comment: Just tick faster - say 10ths of a second, even if you only display whole seconds. That way the variation between timers won't be enough to be visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i Solved this 
i created an array with the pointers to the Label as, Droppy suggested.

This is my updateLabel method that is being called by a Single Timer.

```
(void)updateLabel{
for(int i =0;i<[countdown count];i++){
int seconds,minute,hours,timeleft;
    timeleft = [[countdown objectAtIndex:i]intValue];
    NSLog(@"%i",timeleft);
seconds = timeleft%60;
minute = timeleft/60;
hours = minute /60;
    UILabel *mylabel = [labelArray objectAtIndex:i];
    mylabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i:%i",hours,minute,seconds];
    timeleft --;
    NSLog(@"%@",countdown);
    [countdown replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",timeleft]];
     NSLog(@"%@",countdown);
if(timeleft ==0){
    [timer1 invalidate];
}
}
}
```

This is the content of countdown Array

```
 countdown = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1000" ,@"1523",@"234",@"600",@"900", nil];
```

Hope this helps others that are facing this similar problem

Answer (score 1):

In the object which is "running" the timer, keep a single timer object, which is always running and a list of custom objects that will maintain the "timeleft" and "label" instances to be updated:

LabelTime.h:

```
@interface LabelTime : NSObject
@property NSTimeInterval timeLeft;
@property UILabel *label;
- (void)decrementTime:(NSTimeInteval)interval;
@end
```

LabelTime.m:

```
@interface LabelTime

- (void)decrementTime:(NSTimeInterval)interval {
    NSTimeInterval newTimeLeft = self.timeLeft - interval;
    if (newTimeLeft >= 0.0) {
        self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d seconds left", (int)newTimeLeft];
        // Only if you want whole numbers              ^^                ^^^^^
    }
    self.timeLeft = newTimeLeft;
}

@end
```

someclass.m:

```
#define UPDATE_TIME 1.0

@implementation SomeClass () {
    NSTimer *_timer;
    NSTimeInterval _lastTimeFired;
    NSMutableArray *_labelTimes;     // array of LabelTime objects
}
- (void)_timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer;
@end
```

init them somewhere:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:UPDATE_TIME
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(_timerFired:)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES];
        _lastTimeFired = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
        _labelTimes = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)_timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {
    NSTimeInterval now = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    NSTimeInterval interval = _lastTimeFired - now;
    for (LabelTime *labelTime in _labelTimes) {
        [labelTime decrementTime:interval];
    }
    _lastTimeFired = now;
}
```

Notes:

- You might want to "lock" read/write access to `_labelTimes` to ensure thread safety.